# How to apply Transdisciplinarity Logic to Truth Tables?

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

I've been having trouble trying to figure out Transdisciplinarity Logic. I have had little success while trying to research on my own, finding sources that are either too difficult to understand or too general. [This](https://www.metanexus.net/transdisciplinary-logic-transdisciplinarity/) is probably the best source I've found, but it doesn't explain T-states in a way I can comprehend. It explains what T-states are *not* instead of what they *are*. I also can't find information on how to implement this logic in truth tables, other than using *A*, *P*, and *T* in place of *T* and *F* in propositional logic truth tables.

If anyone has examples of its application, reliable sources, information regarding truth tables or the T-state, or even just pointing me in the right direction, I would be extremely grateful. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: For Transdisciplinarity you can see [Basarab Nicolescu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basarab_Nicolescu)

Comment: And see J.Brenner, [Logic in Reality](https://books.google.it/books?id=Jnj5E6C9UwsC&pg=PR3)

Comment: If, as per the link, LIR is "non-propositional, non-truth-functional logic", you cannot.

Comment: There are references to: [Paraconsistent Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-paraconsistent/), [Intuitionistic Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) and [Quantum Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-quantlog/)